# Gatsby contentful error:not able to start Gatsby after installing this plugin

Tags: gatsby, contentful

There was an error in your GraphQL query:

> Unknown type "ContentfulSizes". Did you mean "ContentfulBlogPost",
>   "ContentfulBlogPostSys", "ContentfulContentType", or
>   "ContentfulBlogPostEdge"?  File:
>   node_modules\gatsby-source-contentful\src\fragments.js:223:47

I am getting this error, by running the development server of Gatsby after installing and enabling the gatsby-source-contentful plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue with Contentful plugin, you can check for further information in this thread of [Gatsby GitHub repository](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/15397).

The solution is to add a dummy image, whatever you like, as a Contentful media. You don't need even to query it, just to add it in Contentful. This will bypass the issue as a temporary workaround while they fix it in further upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

The only suitable solution is
Delete The following File:

**node_modules/gatsby-source-contentful/src/fragments.js**

Comment: This is not a proper solution because the error will persist in every `yarn`/`npm install`